# Aggregation binding not working in AreaMicroChart

Tags: sapui5

I have bound `JSONModel` with `sap.suite.ui.microchart.AreaMicroChart` control to show *points* in *lines* `aggregation` but chart is not rendering.

Plese tell me whats wrong in below `XML` code:

```
<micro:AreaMicroChart lines="{/}" id="areaMicroChart" isResponsive="true" minXValue="0" app:name="area" maxXValue="12" minYValue="0" maxYValue="999999" colorPalette="#b6d957" press="press">
    <micro:firstXLabel>
        <micro:AreaMicroChartLabel label="Jan" />
    </micro:firstXLabel>
    <micro:lastXLabel>
        <micro:AreaMicroChartLabel label="Dec" />
    </micro:lastXLabel>
    <micro:firstYLabel>
        <micro:AreaMicroChartLabel label="" color="Good" />
    </micro:firstYLabel>
    <micro:lastYLabel>
        <micro:AreaMicroChartLabel label="" />
    </micro:lastYLabel>
    <micro:lines>
        <micro:AreaMicroChartItem points="{path: 'aPrev', templateShareable: 'true' }">
            <micro:points>
                <micro:AreaMicroChartPoint x="{a}" y="{ZtotalSales}" />
            </micro:points>
        </micro:AreaMicroChartItem>
    </micro:lines>

</micro:AreaMicroChart>
```

`JS` Code:

```
onInit: function() {
    var aPrevMonths = [{
        ZtotalSales: "2123",
        a: "1"
    }, {
        ZtotalSales: "55545",
        a: "2"
    }, {
        ZtotalSales: "34342",
        a: "3"
    }];
    var oModel = new JSONModel({
        aPrev: aPrevMonths

    });
    this.byId("areaMicroChart").setModel(oModel);
}
```

Comment: Any error in the development tools?

Comment: No error, that is why its difficult to figure out for me whats wrong here!

Comment: Pretty sure you need to replace lines="{/}" with lines="{/aPrev}".

Comment: If you set the model to the control itself, do you need the lines at all? I would have thought the points binding would have handled it. Although Im not too fimilar with charts.

Comment: @DanielAlmeida I tried that too, it doesn't work.
@Keith I thought the same but as this chart has multiple `aggregations` need to specify `lines` along with the `template` for `points`

Comment: @Dopedev did you replace the path at points after replacing the lines path ? You could always try to update your model to something like
aPrev : { data: [ **your data here**] }
Afterwards, bind the lines to /aPrev and the points to 'data'

Comment: @DanielAlmeida that doesn't work either :( This seems to be the binding issue than the structure of data.

Comment: With the lines aggregration, does "{>/}" work in the same way?

Comment: Yes that is for named model; but there should be name of model before > like {sales>/}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I hit the same issue I wanted to share the solution I found to work for me. The `microchart` is very particular on the datatype you provide in the data binding. So to assure it works you need to make sure you sent in true numbers. In the case of the provided example, the data structure should container numbers rather than strings. So it should look something like:

```
var aPrevMonths = [{
    ZtotalSales: 2123,
    a: 1
}, {
    ZtotalSales: 55545,
    a: 2
}, {
    ZtotalSales: 34342,
    a: 3
}];
```

Hope this helps somebody else!